# Complexity of recursive calls

Tags: algorithms, complexity, recursion, big-o

my brain is a little stuck as I am trying to compile an example for my blog. I am presenting an algorithm that draws a number from an array, adds it to a sum and calls itself recursively.

```swift
func solve(coins: Array<Int>, target: Int) -> Int {

    func _solve(coins: Array<Int>, current: Int) -> Int {

        var candidates = coins
        var crt = current
        while candidates.count > 0 {
            // pop() removes the element at the head and returns it
            let rdm: Int = candidates.pop() 

            if (current + rdm) > target {
                continue
            }

            crt = _solve(candidates, current: current + rdm)

            if crt == target {
                return crt
            }

        }
        return crt
    }

    return _solve(coins, current: 0)
}
```

What this algorithm is doing is, given a set of coins, try to approach a given target as close as possible.

What is the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: What language is this? how is variable target visible to the inside function?

Comment: It is Swift. I guessed it should be clear enough to be considered almost as pseudocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter that you pick the next coin randomly rather than systematically. You're still potentially trying out all subsets of a multiset of size N, so it may take as many as 2^N tries, and that's your (upper bound) complexity.

Comment: Wouldn't the complexity be independent of array size but be constant time? When the target is hit, it's hit.

Comment: So what? When an array is sorted, it's sorted - that doesn't make the sort constant time.

Comment: @Kilian Foth You are right. It does not matter that it is random. I updated the question to simplify by removing the random function.

Comment: @Kilian Foth Apart from that, thank you for the answer, could you please update it with a link to some theory as I am trying to wrap my head around it a little bit better?

Comment: @MikeM If you're looking for general info on the theory of algorithm analysis, see [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) and its links on CS.SE.

Comment: @MikeM If you're looking for why the number of tries is 2^N specifically, look into [power sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) and their properties.